# Metal looks different in lookdev and render

Tags: rendering

I'm using the Poliigon material converter and a texture from Poliigon. 
I chose the metalness download and in lookdev it looks very good, but in the render it just looks plain and not metallic. When searching for an answer I'm pretty sure it has to do with the lighting. So I changed the HDR in render to the same studio.exr but it doesn't look any good. 
What can be done?

The top one is lookdev mode with studio HDR

The bottom on is render (Cycles, 600) with studio HDR

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't get the file size down smaller than around 50mb. Now I tried with just a cube and the texture but it's the same and the file size remains. Tried packing the files into blender file.

Comment: Seems like the texture makes the file size very large, the folder that contains the texture is 55mb. Tried saving with compression but no difference. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: I think that it is uploaded now, sorry I'm so new to this. But now the texture file is not packed in there. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=exZGjK13" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/exZGjK13/)

Comment: Proper way is to add this code into your question (simply via "edit" at bottom of your question). I did it. I guess we can delete all comments here (easier for followers). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles **Render** View
[image]

Cycles **Lookdev** View
[image]

I would say you don't use the same lightning setup for render and lookdev. Render use World and Scene Lights / Lookdev Studio light.

In the file you provided I can't confirm you use studio HDR for render, also if would use the same HDR for lookdev and  render, difference will does studio lights that are not taken into lightning in lookdev.

---

If I (for example) disable Studio Lights and Scene World I can see Render and Lookdev in both Cycles and Eevee matchs.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I think i missed the studio lights in this file that I uploaded (made a new when trying to make it smaller). But anyway, you are completely right. As in many of these questions why it looks different in render it must depend on the light. Now I tried with an emission plane above the model 10x10 meters and it completely changed the look of it. Thanks for your help, I'll mark this as solved.